# finding gcd: not all control paths return a value

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    else {
        gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}
```

When I try to calculate the greatest common divisor,
I know that I have to call `return gcd(b,a%b)` not `gcd(b,a%b)`.
But I don't understand the reason why.
Doesn't b become 0 at some point?

Comment: Let's say you call `gcd(1, 1)`. So `b == 0` is `false`, so it takes the `else` path... and then what does it return? Nothing, because you didn't put a `return` there.

Comment: Please be aware of what tags you use. This has nothing to do whatsoever with [tag:grand-central-dispatch] tag.

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function for the first time。
if `b!=0`
it will continue to execute `else gcd(b, a % b);` 
But the function you called for the first time have no return value.

The following code will help you understand recursion：

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    else {
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}

int calc_gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    else {
        gcd(b, a % b);
        // return ?
    }
}
```

call function `calc_gcd` is equivalent to call `gcd` in your code.
missing return value.
The right recursive function would work be like this:

```
gcd0                                         ... return value to user
   gcd1                                 .... ↑ 
      gcd2                         .... ↑
         gcd3 .... pass value to ↑
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not really have to do

```
return gcd(b,a%b)
```

but it is the easiest way to do it.

You seem to understand that you have to return in all situations an int from a function with a head like

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
```

Doing in both branches of an if is a short way to do so.

It can be argued that for side goals like readability, maintainability, robustness etc. the very last statement of an int-returning functions should always be a `return SomeInt;`. But it not so easy to do that in a way which also does not get an "unreachable code" complaint by many static analysis tools. A local variable `int returnValue`, initialised to a wisely selected default and written in all branches could get you there.
But again, some tools then complain that a value is written to a variable which is then always overwritten before being used... So the default init could be to `a` and then not be overwritten in "then". Making analysis tools happy sometimes is a game of loop-the-loops...

By the way, the code you show might (absolutely no guarantee) actually work, because compilers sometimes return the last calculated result by default, even if it was ignored. But you should definitly never rely on that and deserve any complaint you get, by humans or tools. We can safely consider that to be a BadIdea(tm).